# Search for Substrings in Object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this code.

```
var abc = { QSX: 'V',WRT: 'VC',ETH: 'VC',RHY: 'VC',TFG: 'VC',YKL: 'VC'}
var filtered = _.pick(abc, ['HY', 'H']); //Lodash
console.log(filtered);
```

It should output the following:

> filtered = {RHY: 'VC', ETH: 'VC'}

Because those are the only two items that contain the substrings 'HY' and 'H'.
But it outputs just the first item. 
Can someone help me figuring out why please?

Comment: [`_.pickBy(object, [predicate=_.identity])`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pickBy)

Answer (score 1):

Lodash matches exact property names in [`_.pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick). It doesn't pick the properties partially matching the given items.

If you want partial match, you should use [`_.pickBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pickBy) instead.

```js
var abc = { QSX: 'V',WRT: 'VC',ETH: 'VC',RHY: 'VC',TFG: 'VC',YKL: 'VC'}
var filtered = _.pick(abc, ['HY', 'H']); //Lodash
console.log(filtered);
filtered = _.pickBy(abc, (v, k) => k.includes('HY') || k.includes('H'));
console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: But, It requires manually adding `||` through all the inputes right, I think OP want to pass all the inputs as a array in one go.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee -- well there are a number of ways to achieve. I don't say my solution is full-proof, and is what the OP needs. It just gets the OP a step closer to what he wants, and the solution can further be changed as per the need.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var abc = {
  QSX: 'V',
  WRT: 'VC',
  ETH: 'VC',
  RHY: 'VC',
  TFG: 'VC',
  YKL: 'VC'
}
var filterBase = ['HY', 'H']

var filtered = _.pickBy(abc, function(value, key) {
  var isThere = _.find(filterBase, function(o) {
   
    return key.indexOf(o) !== -1
  })
  return isThere
}); //Lodash
console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

You may try this . Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it with punching `lodash#pickBy` and native `filter` (however you can again use lodash, but not required), in a one liner.

Have a look:

assume `filterWith` is the array as filter input

`_.pickBy(abc, (v,k) => filterWith.find(f=> k.match(f)));`

Here is an working snippet:

```js
var abc = { QSX: 'V',WRT: 'VC',ETH: 'VC',RHY: 'VC',TFG: 'VC',YKL: 'VC'};
var filterWith = ['HY', 'H'];

var filtededData = _.pickBy(abc, (v,k) => filterWith.find(f=> k.match(f)));

console.log(filtededData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```